# have to press twice the button to work

Tags: javascript, java, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi guys I am developing an android app which is totally running using html,bootstrap and CSS. But for some cases i used native code android.Now the problem is that while i was clicking the text box in the html ,native keyboard is popping up and while I click any html button firstly the keyboard is removed and then i have to click again then the button is working .I have to press twice the button .Please help.It is working fine on Genymotion emulator but not working on real device .

I am using Motorola turbo edition [image]

Buttons are below

```
 <!--Approval Buttons Section-->
    <div ng-show="!vc.isApprDtlsSuccessShown && !vc.isApprDtlsOTPShown"
         class="t-approval-btn-block">
        <div class="t-approval-btn-box"> <!--Removed ng-disabled="vc.disableButtons"-->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pink-btn"
                    ng-click="vc.setStatus('APR', 'approvalDetails')">APPROVE
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="t-approval-btn-box m_top10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pink-btn"
                    ng-click="vc.setStatus('REJ', 'approvalDetails')">REJECT
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="t-approval-btn-box m_top10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pink-btn"
                    ng-click="vc.setStatus('APH', 'approvalDetails')">APPROVE AND HOLD
            </button>
        </div>
```

Css are below

```
 .t-approval-btn-box {
```

text-align: center;
}

```
.pink-btn {
width: 281px;
height: 48px;
background-color: #fb637e;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
border: none;
font-size: 16px;
```

}

```
.m_top10 {
margin-top: 10px;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried changing the device?

Comment: Yes I have changed the device to nexus 5 .But no luck same issue.

Comment: Can you share the code in which button is clicked?

Comment: I have updated the css and buttons  Html

Comment: Your code seems to be fine.